# CSS Grid System for Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I am developing a [personal website](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jsani), which is currently in a very crude state. I am working on improving the website's style.

I have finished and styled the top row, my name and the nav bar, using a file called grid.css, which can be seen in the source code of the site. I took that file from teamtreehouse.com in their "Build a Simple Website" tutorial because I thought it would be easy to implement that grid. For some reason, the grid works perfectly for the top row, with my name spanning 3 columns and the nav bar spanning 9, but when I did the same division for the image and the About Me blurb, the blurb goes down to the next row. Why?

The relevant code is below:

```
<div class="grid_3">
    <img src="img/JayantSani.jpg" width="75%" height="75%" alt="Jayant Sani">
</div>
<div id="about" class="grid_9 omega">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <p>Hi there! I'm Jayant Sani. I'm currently a freshman at Harvard University interested in      studying computer science. I expect to graduate in 2017. I like traveling, sports, and developing web and mobile apps.</p>  
</div>
```

The grid_(number) classes come from the grid.css file, which is accessible via viewing the source of the website linked above.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Pls post the relevant code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not contain  the code relevant to the question.

Comment: I have just edited the question to contain the correct code. I thought linking the website was enough to view the source, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `<div class="grid_3">`has a computed height in the broswer of 37 pixels and the Menu to the left has a computed height of 20px.

Your 2nd grid 3 (the image) is floating left under the 20px. because it does not have a clear:left css rule applied it is draw to the right of the first grid_3. The solution from the code recently posted is ...

```
<div class="grid_3" style="clear:left">
    <img src="img/JayantSani.jpg" width="75%" height="75%" alt="Jayant Sani">
</div>
```

You used teamtreehouse.com's term CSS grid system for layout, not your fault but sparked a WTF response from me.

http://caniuse.com/css-grid CSS grid is new to CSS3 and not yet supported by browsers.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #grid {
    display: grid;

    /* Two columns: the first sized to content, the second receives
     * the remaining space, but is never smaller than the minimum 
     * size of the board or the game controls, which occupy this 
     * column. */
    grid-template-columns: auto minmax(min-content, 1fr);

    /* Three rows: the first and last sized to content, the middle 
     * row receives the remaining space, but is never smaller than 
     * the minimum height of the board or stats areas. */
    grid-template-rows: auto minmax(min-content, 1fr) auto
  }

  /* Each part of the game is positioned between grid lines by 
   * referencing the starting grid line and then specifying, if more 
   * than one, the number of rows or columns spanned to determine 
   * the ending grid line, which establishes bounds for the part. */
  #title    { grid-column: 1; grid-row: 1 }
  #score    { grid-column: 1; grid-row: 3 }
  #stats    { grid-column: 1; grid-row: 2; justify-self: start }
  #board    { grid-column: 2; grid-row: 1 / span 2; }
  #controls { grid-column: 2; grid-row: 3; align-self: center }
</style>
```

**Update easiest CSS coding.**

Add this CSS rule to any of the CSS files, you have to many to look though.

```
*[nextrow] {
   clear:left;
}
```

Then use it as an attribute when you want to go to the next row.

```
<div class="grid_3" nextrow>
```

Comment: I added a CSS solution, and fixed a missing " I'm using an international keyboard and sometimes I forget to hit space after typing a " and the " does not get entered. Or it gets placed someplace else.